# Read text file with Pyspark and add it to array by each word

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I need to read with pyspark a text file and create a dataframe with only one string Array which matches the Output provided below.

Input:

Text file

```
I like my job
I hate my job
```

Output:

```
Array(I, like, my, job, I, hate, my, job)
```

My current solution:

```
text_path = ""
df = spark.read.text(text_path)

df_transformed = df.agg(F.concat_ws(" ", F.collect_list('value')).alias('value'))
df_transformed = df_transformed .select(F.split(F.col("value")," ").alias("Array"))
```

Which does not represent the required output:

[image] [image]

What am I missing here? Some formatting, data type, different printing?

Comment: How is your output different from the expected output?

Comment: @viggnah - casing maybe.